# How to solve this error Script 'C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' and 'C:\src\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'

Tags: flutter, build.gradle

I'm getting this error and I have  tried some solutions but unable to resolved.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1005
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

> Process 'command 'C:\src\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 6m 35s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Any suggestions are welcomed.

Comment: Can you give more information why this happens? Did you just migrate to null-safety?

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1**

Maybe this outdated but should help someone.

Yesterday I Just restarted my pc and got this issue. I tried to search for the solution to this problem but nothing works in my case .

**Solution**
Just delete your flutter folder (Flutter Source) and then reinstall it. Your problem will solve.

**Solution 2**
I was able to get around this by running with null safety turned off. See this article for details.

```
dart --no-sound-null-safety run
flutter run --no-sound-null-safety
```